# Node.js Express not rendering html view

Tags: node.js, wordpress, express

so I was trying to follow a tutorial to use node.js as the front end of a wordpress site

This one http://www.1001.io/improve-wordpress-with-nodejs/

Here is the code from server.js

```
var frnt = require('frnt');
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var doT = require('express-dot');

// Define where the public files are, in this example ./public
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Make sure this is set before the frnt middleware, otherwise you won't
// be able to create custom routes.
app.use(app.router);

// Setup the frnt middleware with the link to the internal server
app.use(frnt.init({
    proxyUrl: "http://localhost:8888/frnt-example/wordpress", // The link to your wordpress site
    layout: false // We simplify this example by not using layouts
}));

// define rendering engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set('view engine', 'html' );
app.engine('html', doT.__express );

// respond with "Hello World!" on the homepage
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('./views/index.html');
});

app.listen(8080); // listen to port 8080
```

It keeps outputting the following

./views/index.html

Rather than rendering the html?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used frnt, but res.send sends a string so that's no big surprise.

Look at res.sendfile which sends the contents of a file.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `ejs` , it's sems like html just edit `index.html` to `index.ejs`
1- install ejs module `npm install ejs`
2- add this in app.js

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

and render the index.ejs by using

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index'); // or res.render('index.ejs');
});
```

res.send() // it send just a string not file

Hope it usefull !